Can an electronic signature API be integrated into Appsheet?
For a few months now I have been working on a project to integrate an electronic signature API called Viafirma, which has not yet been proven to be integrated into Appsheet. It should be noted that the PDF documents generated by my app will be sent to sign through this integration which has not been achieved because this error persists:

" Request failed for https://sandbox.viafirma.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: {"code":404,"type":" ERROR","message":"HTTP 404 Not Found","trace":"1210a16cd6ad417ca238bb493428ed29"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)"

It should be noted that the protocol used in the development is oauth2 and the integration It requests a callback from AppSheet but I don't know how I can search for it in my app and in any case if AppSheet is able to support this type of request.
CODE:
// Se Definen las Constantes de Autenticación y la URL Base
const OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXXX'; // 'tu_consumer_key' clave de consumidor de OAuth de Viafirma.
const OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXXXXX'; // 'tu_consumer_secret' clave de consumidor de OAuth de Viafirma.
const VIAFIRMA_BASE_URL = 'https://sandbox.viafirma.com/documents/api/v3'; // URL base del entorno sandbox de Viafirma.
const FOLDER_ID = 'XXXXXXX'; // ID de la carpeta en Google Drive donde se almacenan los archivos

// Función para Obtener el Token OAuth
function obtenerTokenOAuth() {
  const OAUTH_TOKEN_URL = `${VIAFIRMA_BASE_URL}/oauth2/token`;
  
  const options = {
    method: 'post', // Método HTTP POST.
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY + ':' + OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET) // Base64 encode the client id and secret
    },
    payload: {
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials' // Tipo de concesión de OAuth.
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true // Para obtener la respuesta completa en caso de error.
  };
  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(OAUTH_TOKEN_URL, options); // Se Realiza la solicitud para obtener el token.
  
  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
    Logger.log(response.getContentText()); // Registra el contenido de la respuesta
    throw new Error('Error al obtener el token OAuth: ' + response.getContentText());
  }
  
  const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); // Se Analiza la respuesta JSON.
  return jsonResponse.access_token; // Se Devuelve el token de acceso.
}

// Función para leer datos desde la hoja de cálculo y firmar documentos
function leerDatosYFirmarDocumentos() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DATOS FORM'); // Nombre de tu hoja en Google Sheets.
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Obtiene todos los datos de la hoja.
  
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const IDATS = data[i][0]; // Asume que la primera columna tiene el IDATS
    const DOCUMENTO = data[i][14]; // Asume que la segunda columna tiene la URL del documento

    if (IDATS && DOCUMENTO) {
      try {
        firmarDocumento(IDATS, DOCUMENTO);
      } catch (error) {
        Logger.log(`Error al firmar el documento con IDATS ${IDATS}: ${error.message}`);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log(`IDATS o DOCUMENTO no definido para la fila ${i + 1}`);
    }
  }
}

// Crear un nuevo conjunto de documentos
function crearNuevoSet(token) {
  const payload = {
    "name": "Conjunto de Documentos a Firmar"
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${VIAFIRMA_BASE_URL}/sets`, options);
  const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return jsonResponse.id; // ID del nuevo conjunto de documentos
}

// Función para Firmar el Documento
function firmarDocumento(IDATS, DOCUMENTO) {
  if (!DOCUMENTO) {
    throw new Error('La ruta del archivo no está definida');
  }
  const token = obtenerTokenOAuth(); // Obtén el token de acceso OAuth.

  // Paso 1: Se crea un nuevo conjunto de documentos
  const setId = crearNuevoSet(token);

  // Paso 2: Se Agrega el documento al conjunto
  agregarDocumentoAlSet(token, setId, IDATS, DOCUMENTO);

  // Paso 3: Se Envia el conjunto para firma
  enviarSetParaFirma(token, setId);

  // Se guarda la URL del documento firmado en Google Sheets (puede necesitar ajustes)
  guardarSignedUrlEnSheet(IDATS, `https://sandbox.viafirma.com/documents/api/v3/sets/${setId}`);
}


// Agregar un documento al conjunto
function agregarDocumentoAlSet(token, setId, IDATS, DOCUMENTO) {
  const filePath = DOCUMENTO.split('/').pop(); // Extrae solo el nombre del archivo
  const fileId = obtenerFileId(filePath);

  const payload = {
    "name": IDATS, // Nombre del documento (ID o nombre identificativo).
    "contentType": "application/pdf", // Tipo de contenido del documento.
    "content": obtenerContenidoBase64(fileId) // Contenido del documento en base64.
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${VIAFIRMA_BASE_URL}/sets/${setId}/documents`, options);
  const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return jsonResponse.id; // ID del documento agregado al conjunto
}

// Enviar el conjunto para firma
function enviarSetParaFirma(token, setId) {
  const payload = {
    "recipients": [
      {
        "type": "SIGNER",
        "identifier": {
          "type": "EMAIL",
          "value": "signer@example.com" // Reemplaza con el email del firmante
        },
        "name": "Firmante Ejemplo"
      }
    ],
    "callback": {
      "url": "https://tudominio.com/callback" // Reemplaza con tu URL de callback
    }
  };

  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${VIAFIRMA_BASE_URL}/sets/${setId}/send`, options);
  const jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return jsonResponse;
}

function obtenerFileId(filePath) {
  if (!filePath) {
    throw new Error('La ruta del archivo no está definida');
  }

  // Extraer el ID del archivo de la ruta
  const folderId = FOLDER_ID; // Se Reemplaza con el ID del DRIVE
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId); // Se Reemplaza 'FOLDER_ID' con el ID de la carpeta donde se almacenan los archivos
  const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop(); // Se obtiene el archivo por nombre

  const files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

  if (files.hasNext()) {
    return files.next().getId();
  } else {
    throw new Error('Archivo no encontrado: ' + filePath);
  }
}

// Función para Obtener el Contenido en Base64
function obtenerContenidoBase64(fileId) {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId); // Se Realiza la solicitud para obtener el contenido del archivo.
  const blob = file.getBlob(); // Se Obtiene el blob del archivo.
  return Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes()); // Se Codifica el blob en base64 y lo devuelve.
}

// Función para Guardar la URL Firmada en Google Sheets
function guardarSignedUrlEnSheet(IDATS, signedUrl) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DATOS FORM'); // Reemplaza 'NombreDeTuHoja' con el nombre de tu hoja en Google Sheets.
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Obtiene todos los datos de la hoja.
  
  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] === IDATS) {  // Busca el ID del documento en la primera columna.
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 16).setValue(signedUrl);  // Guarda la URL firmada en la columna 16.
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Llama a la función para leer datos y firmar documentos
leerDatosYFirmarDocumentos();

I would be very grateful if you could help me by telling me if this type of integration is possible or in any case if there is some type of error in my code, let me know. I am open to continuing learning and hearing your comments.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question needs more focus.

In Google Apps Script projects, including a function called the top level / global scope might cause problems.
Despite other problems that might be present, the following code lines should be removed
// Llama a la función para leer datos y firmar documentos
leerDatosYFirmarDocumentos();

A Google Apps Script JavaScript runtime doesn't work the same way the JavaScript runtime of a web browser. Whenever a function is called from the user interface of an integration like AppSheet, everything on the top-level global scope is executed. It's like reloading a webpage, events like onload occur, and everything listening to events like this is executed.
